# How much of Augustine's writing has been translated into English?

Tags: soft-question, augustinus

<sup>(I'm not entirely sure that this is an appropriate question for the site: feel free to comment or start a meta discussion if you disagree.) I'm also not sure what tag(s) would be most appropriate.</sup>

Often, when asked about some of the practical benefits of studying Latin, I answer that a great deal of important works--particularly post-classical and medieval--are not available in modern translation. A prime example of this is [Augustine of Hippo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augustine_of_Hippo) (AD 354-430), an immensely influential and prolific Christian writer.

This [faculty page from Georgetown](http://faculty.georgetown.edu/jod/augustine/textstrans.html) states that Augustine has never been fully translated into English:

> Augustine left behind 5,000,000 words that survive today.... **No complete English translation has ever been achieved of all his works.**

I will restrict this question to English translations, though I'd also be curious about any other modern language.

**Approximately how much of Augustine's work has been translated into English?** If possible, I would also like to see a **list of his untranslated works**.

Comment: What's a "soft question?"

Comment: I think latin.stackexchange.com is the most appropriate forum on the Internet to ask this question.

Comment: I think the question is very appropriate. I think we should have a tag that for questions like "has this thing been translated?", but I'm not sure what to call it. Perhaps "has-it-been-translated"?

Comment: @C.M.Weimer A soft question is a meta question of some kind, not about the subject matter itself (answering requires no knowledge of Latin language) but something related. Some sites have a "big-picture" tag in addition to "soft-question", and it has a similar spirit. Perhaps we ought to have [a tag description](https://latin.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/276)...

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta My instincts are saying that there is a more appropriate tag for questions like these, perhaps [tag:resource-request]? To answer your meta-question, brianpck, I do wholly support questions like these on this site, though I worry about the potential for silly questions like "Is Ovid translated into English?" We can take them on a case-by-case basis, though.

Comment: The quote you give—"No complete English translation has ever been achieved of all his works."—makes me wonder whether *no single author* has ever translated all of his works. Is it possible that this is meant instead? It's hard to imagine that one of his works has not been translated, considering all the Latinists and theologians who have translated him over the years.